# Using knowledge of derivatives, what is f(x), when $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2} - sec^2x$ with initial condition f($0$)=$1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Second part of it is anti-derivitive of $\,\tan x\,$
I am having hard time with fraction in first part. I know it can written
as $(1+x^2)^\frac{1}{2}$?

Thank you!

Comment: The second part is the *derivative* of $\tan x$. And no, you cannot write $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=(1+x^2)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\tan ^{-1}x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: so it is arctan (x) - tan (x) + C? Should I solve for C by f(0) =>  arctan (0) + tan (0) + C = 1?

Comment: Yes, it is. You're absolutely correct. $C$ is going to be $1$.

Comment: Awesome. You guys making me more confident in my calculus. Thank you so much for your time and patience!